# Converting a dictionary to json using json.dumps having arabic characters

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a dictionary containing arabic words like

```
data = [{'name': 'آدَم'}, {'name': 'آزَر'}]
print(json.dumps(data), file=open('data.json', 'a', encoding="utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
[{"name": "\u0622\u0632\u064e\u0631"}...]
```

I don't want to encode the arabic text while creating the data.json file. If I do not use json.dumps then it works fine but then it shows single quotes ' instead of double qoutes "

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pass the parameter `ensure_ascii = False`:

```
json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

> If *ensure_ascii* is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If *ensure_ascii* is false, these characters will be output as-is.

Comment: it works well and it is better to add encoding utf-8
json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')