# reading arabic text from text file and save the output in json

Tags: json, text, encoding, arabic, txt

I performed ocr on images to extract Arabic content. I stored the output in a text file using

```
f=open(filename,'w',encoding='utf-8') 
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

The output in the txt file is readable. But when I read the txt file using

```
file=open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8')
json[name]=file.read()
```

I get this weird encoding that i couldn't solve

[image]

Comment: You're not reading the file as UTF 8

Comment: I've tried with encoding='utf-8' .Still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem is from json when using dump I changed ensure_ascii=False and it kept it as it is.
[same problem but in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486382/converting-a-dictionary-to-json-using-json-dumps-having-arabic-characters)